# JSON format mismatch in generating DataTables from Ajax source

Tags: json, datatables

I wish to generate a DataTable with ajax response as the source. I convert an ArrayList of employees to JSON string using GSON libraries. The JSON string I get is

```
{
"sEcho": 3,
"iTotalRecords": 2,
"iTotalDisplayRecords": 2,
"aaData": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "firstName": "darsheet",
        "lastName": "shah",
        "city": "san jose",
        "state": "ca",
        "zip": 95112
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "firstName": "akshat",
        "lastName": "shah",
        "city": "ahmedabad",
        "state": "gj",
        "zip": 380061
    }
]
```

}

But the sAjaxSource attribute requires JSON string in following format

```
{
"sEcho": 3,
"iTotalRecords": 2,
"iTotalDisplayRecords": 2,
"aaData": [
    {
        "0": 1,
        "1": "darsheet",
        "2": "shah",
        "3": "san jose",
        "4": "ca",
        "5": 95112
    },
    {
        "0": 2,
        "1": "akshat",
        "2": "shah",
        "3": "ahmedabad",
        "4": "gj",
        "5": 380061
    }
]
```

}

The Datatable code I use is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#refresh').click(function(){
    $('#emp').dataTable({
        "sAjaxSource":".../ExploreDatatable/loadTableAjax"  
    });

});
});
```

How to remove this mismatch in JSON structure ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know it's that you option of datatable is wrong. it should do it like this:

```
$('#emp').dataTable({
        "sAjaxSource":".../ExploreDatatable/loadTableAjax",
        "aoColumns": [{"mDataProp": "id"},
                      {"mDataProp": "firstName"},
                         .....the other column names, that should be mapped to the json key......
                     ］
    });
```